# set html content based on a certaint data attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have this list with data attributes

```
<li id="1"><a href="#" class="me"  data-lrnumero="1">Hello</a></li>
<li id="2"><a href="#" class="me"  data-lrnumero="2">Hello</a></li>
<li id="3"><a href="#" class="me"  data-lrnumero="3">Hello</a></li>
<li id="4"><a href="#" class="me"  data-lrnumero="4">Hello</a></li>
<li id="5"><a href="#" class="me"  data-lrnumero="5">Hello</a></li>
```

I want set content based on `data-lrnumero`. For example, when I click on the `<a>`, get data-lrnumero value then set content to `hello (value of data attribute)` only on this `<a>`

**EDIT:**

I set variable id on `<li>` , for example `<li id="1">`, then I create a function

```
$('.me').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "someurl",
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data == 'true') {
              var iddata= $(this).data('lrnumero');
              $('#' + iddata).empty();                   
              $('#' + iddata).html('<a href="#" class="me"  data-lrnumero='+iddata+'>Hello '+iddata+'</a>');
            }
        });
    });
```

But is a bit complex. I want set only get the data attribute of the `<a>` then set the new content

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Reading the jQuery doc, might be a good place to start. here a tuto to help you start : https://forum.jquery.com/topic/getting-the-value-of-a-custom-attribute

Comment: Yes, I edit my answer. I made it works, but its complex. I would find a solution withoud addind id to the `<li>`

Comment: Have updated answer below to avoid replacing the LI (so you do not need an ID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/oecgvtto/1/

```
$('li a').click(function(e){
    // Stop page jumping to top - as it is a bookmark link
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text("Hello " + $(this).data('lrnumero'));
});
```

For your new example code you need to retain the clicked element, in a local var (e.g. `$this` below), and not replace it the whole LI by ID!:

```
$('.me').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "someurl",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data == 'true') {
            var iddata = $this.data('lrnumero');
            $this.text("Hello " + iddata);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I try it and I get "Hello NaN" when I set `$this.text = "Hello " + iddata;`

Comment: Sorry, typo. Should have remained as `text()`. iddata is from the clicked anchor. If there is a problem still, please provide a JSFiddle link to your complete code so I can check it.

Comment: Due to your support, I get the solution.

I move `var iddata = $this.data('lrnumero');` to top, below `e.preventDefault`. Then, it works. MANY THANKS!

Comment: @Giancarlo Ventura Granados: Glad you got there in the end, but moving that line should not have been needed. If it was still `$(this)` instead of `$this` it would break, but I am curious why it failed.

Comment: I replaced the `$this` with `var somevariable = $(this);`, Then it works fine for me. Maybe `var $this` is variable name asignation problem

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following:

```
var data = [];
$('li a').each(function(){
    data.push($(this).html());  
})

console.log(data);
$('li').click(function(){
    element = $(this).find('a');
    element.html(data[$('li').index(this)]+element.data('lrnumero'));
});
```

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: This will keep appending on every click. e.g. keep clicking link 2 and you will get `Hello2222`:  http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/oecgvtto/2/

Comment: Right: you should do save them and then start adding the value

Comment: Actually that is now worse. Check the newly added code in the question as the question has changed a lot.